# Django + uwsgi in emperor mode: how to reload wsgi.py of a project

Tags: django, uwsgi

I was deploying a new project on my server but regrettably in wsgi.py of Django project folder, I have had settings for another project (copy-paste and I forget to change it). My wsgi.py looked like this:

```
import os

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "loserti.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Instead of "loserti.settings" there should have been "cwu.settings". Of course, my project did not work complaing that it cannot find loserti.settings. I have fixed the problem and reloaded the appropriate uwsgi vassal (`uwsgi --reload`) which I do when I change some python code but that did not help in this case. So I have tried to reload the emperor. That did not help either. In the end I needed to stop and start the emperor which seems definitely to be an overkill. Please, what is the correct way to do that?

Comment: Did you manage to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the answer is that this

`os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "loserti.settings")`

reset the environment variable `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` only if it has not been set yet for the vassal. The thing is that you need to actually kill the vassal (using SIGKILL) so that it is respawned fresh by  emperor. After that that change is finally applied.

Answer (score 8):

just "touch" the configuration file of your vassal. This will trigger a reload of the whole vassal

Comment: Is it any different from what I did? `uwsgi --reload vassal.pid`

Comment: nope, I have tried to modify wsgi.py and then touch the vassal conf, vassal reloaded but the change did not apply